# How to sort a list that contains both numbers and letters?

Tags: python

I am trying to join and sort some list that contains numbers and letters

for example:

```
l1 = ['AF', '0.167']
l2 = ['AF', '1']

l3 = ['AC', '1']
l4 = ['AC', '6']
```

if I join l1 and l2 together, l3 and l4 together and reverse them (wish letters come first), I will get two different results.

```
['0.167', 'AF', '1']
['1', 'AF', '0.167']
--------------------
['6', '1', 'AC']
['AC', '1', '6']
```

why the second one can sort properly , but the first one only switch the positions of numbers.

if I expect to get :`new1 =['AF', '0.167, 1'] , new2 = ['AC', '1, 6']`
How can I change the code.

The code is here:

```
l1 = ['AF', '0.167']
l2 = ['AF', '1']
l3 = ['AC', '1']
l4 = ['AC', '6']
new1 = l1 + l2
new1 = list(set(new1))
new2 = l3 + l4
new2 = list(set(new2))

list(reversed(new1))  
list(reversed(new2))

print( new1 )
print(list(reversed(new1))  )
print('--------------------')
print( new2 )
print(list(reversed(new2))  )
```

Comment: `list(set(...))` does not preserve the order of the original list. If it does, it's by accident.

Comment: Do I understand correct, that the expected result is `l1 + l2`, but with removed duplicates?

Comment: expected result is:new1 =['AF', '0.167, 1'] , new2 = ['AC', '1, 6']

Comment: I mean, the expected result in the generic case. What is a valid input in general, and what's the conversion logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to be clarified:

- Sets are unordered, doing `list(set(thing))` will give you a list with "random" order
- [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#reversed) does exactly what it sounds like, it enables you to iterate in reversed order, it doesn't do any sorting. If you want sorting, use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#reversed)

If I understand correctly, you want your strings to come first, followed by the sorted "numbers" (which are actually strings containing representation of numbers).

To do this, you'll need an appropriate sorting function. Something like the following should work:

```
>>> test1 = ['0.167', 'AF', '1']
>>> test2 = ['6', '1', 'AC']
>>> sort_key = lambda s: float('-inf') if s.isalpha() else float(s)
>>> sorted(test1, key=sort_key)
['AF', '0.167', '1']
>>> sorted(test2, key=sort_key)
['AC', '1', '6']
```

Depending on your data, having dict with strings as keys and a list of numbers as value might make more sense for storing it, and would be simpler to sort.

Comment: what if it contains date like: 2019-01-01 and 2020-11-11?

Comment: You'd need to adjust your key function based on the data. In general, the less uniform your data, the more complicated the key function will get. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html covers pretty-much everything you need to know.